# Laravel - Auth error on page

Tags: laravel-4

If i want to test my Auth page, i get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\app\views\home.blade.php)
```

And this is on my home.blade.php page:

```
<?php
   $username = Auth::user()->username;
   $id       = Auth::id();
   if (Auth::check()) {
?>

Hey, if you see this, than you have been logged in!
<a href="{{ URL::to('logout') }}">Logout</a>

    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
    You have to be logged in!
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Screen from the error: http://prntscr.com/79pix0

But how can i fix this?

Comment: It's not correct to define variables in your view....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using blade template engine, why do you use `php` thags then?

If you want to display values, you can just do this:

```
@if (Auth::check())

Hey,{{ Auth::user()->username }} if you see this, than you have been logged in!

<a href="{{ URL::to('logout') }}">Logout</a>

@else

    You have to be logged in!

@endif
```

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Please approve the answer.